# Would like a good bash/sh debugger tool, in command line or a gui tool

Tags: command-line, debugging, shell-scripting, bash

I would like bash/sh debugger tool, in CLI or GUI that:

- shows variables in use.
- show line of the code in execution
- allow breakpoints
- For unix systems

Some options I tried without success:

- /bin/bash -x
- ddd - is dead and doesn't work properly
- Visualstudio - for windows
- shellcheck - excellent tool for check code, but not for debug.

Comment: [How to debug a bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155551/how-to-debug-a-bash-script)

Comment: I saw that post and tryed all of options there. None of them have what I want (maybe eclipse, that I tryied but couldn't make it work). All of them are good  tools for debugging but not with the features that I listed. Resuming, I want to know if there is a tool like pycharm for debug.

Comment: the [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com) one (not visual studio) seems to have the features you're looking for, step by step interactive debugging and variables values ([there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/346901/34446))

Comment: @Alex Thanks! Is exactly what I was looking for! Please, can you put this comment as an answer? Then I can choose you answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with the [Bash Debug extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rogalmic.bash-debug)

[image: Visual Studio Code with the Bash Debug extension in action]

I have used it just once or twice yet, so I can't say much about how well it works, but it ticks all your boxes.

- Shows used variables in the side pane
- Highlights currently executed line
- Supports breakpoints
- Runs on Mac and Linux